# PHP reduce file size of image

Tags: php, laravel

My application allows users to upload bunch of images which are later sent as an email attachment. The problem shows up if file size of images that are being sent is bigger than email accept.
What I want to do is to reduce file size of image until it is lower then 5MB and this is how I tried to do it:

```
/*..some code...*/
$img_quality = 75;
while (filesize($path) >= 5242880) {
   $img_string = file_get_contents($path);
   $img = imagecreatefromstring($img_string);
   $path = $this->getFilePath($file, $file_section, $entity_id);
   imagejpeg($img, $path, $img_quality);
   $img_quality--;
}
/*..some code...*/

//Functions I am calling
public function getFilePath($upload, $section, $id = null) {
    $path = base_path('../upload').$this->downloadOverwrite($upload, $section, $id);
    if(!$upload) {
        return $path;
    }
    if(!file_exists($path)) {
        return null;
    }
    $tmppath = @tempnam("tmp", "myapp");
    file_put_contents($tmppath, file_get_contents($path));
    return $tmppath;
}
public function downloadOverwrite($upload, $section, $id = null, $config = []) {
    $section = !empty($upload['entity']) ? $upload['entity'] : $section;
    $id = !empty($upload['entity_id']) ? $upload['entity_id'] : $id;
    $path = empty($id) ? "/$section" : "/$section/$id";
    if(!empty($upload)) $path .= "/{$upload['fs_name']}"; 
    return $path;
}
```

This code actually works, but if image file size is too big, it takes too long before image is compressed to desired value. Is there any better solution to do this?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the image down a little maybe to a set 800x600 pixels or something. Even smartphones take pictures with resolutions of 2, 3 or even 4k, which is massive. Only reducing the jpg quality may not cut it always.

Comment: No I haven't. How should I do that? Use the `getimagesize()` and then change it's width and height?

Comment: May take some experimentation, but you could alter the `$img_quality` depending on how much larger the file is, dropping it by 2 per iteration reduces the time by quite a bit.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagescale.php
Yes cou can get the width with getimagesize and calculate a new one, or simple use imagescale with a fixed width. Height will be set automatically to keep aspects.

Comment: @NigelRen you are right, but the longer I read this code, the less sense it makes. Because I am losing a lot on quality, while losing quite a little on file size. Finally it sometimes results in quality = 1, and the size is still too big. What clash suggested may be a much better solution, I just have to find the right way to do it

Comment: You can also do the resize, crop and file size check with javascript. If you do that your server only has to process 1 image

Answer (score 0):

actually yes there is a package which is really popular for manipulating images in php which has good integration with laravel :

```
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation
```

so with this package you do as below :

```
$ php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

and after adding aliases if laravel < 5.5 you publish vendor files :

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravelRecent"
```

then you can replace image handling to this :

```
// create instance
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// resize image to fixed size
$img->resize(300, 200);
```

to resize or do any thing like prevent upsizing like :

```
// prevent possible upsizing
$img->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```

or any thing you would like to do according to documentation .
hope this helps

Comment: While resizing may be an option, I still don't see how it should directly impact on my problem. What I mean is, does `Image::make()`  return an instance on which I can later use `filesize()` to determine if it is lower then 5MB (that's what I need). If so, than I need to create loop in which I am going to repetitively decrease the numbers I am forwarding as parameters to `->resize()` and check the `filesize()` every time after the image is resized

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has similiar problem, here is the loop that I used in the end and that worked pretty well for me. May not be the best solution out there, but it's fair enough:

```
$image_width = getimagesize($path)[0];
while (filesize($path) >= 5242880) {
    $image_width -= 50;
    $img_string = file_get_contents($path);
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($img_string);
    $path = $this->getFilePath($file, $file_section, $entity_id);
    $img = imagescale($img, $image_width);
    imagejpeg($img, $path);
}
```

I am lowering the width of the image, while height is being lowered automatically respecting the aspect ratio. This results in pretty fast file size drop, while keeping the quality of image at approximately the same level as it was before scaling.